# py2app opencv deployment

Tags: python, opencv, py2app

I am using opencv im my project. Project builds success and executes well. But when I am trying relocate my app to another folder, I see error:

```
    MacBook-Air-Voldemar:tmp voldemar$ ./Paranoid.app/Contents/MacOS/Paranoid 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/tmp/Paranoid.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 316, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/private/tmp/Paranoid.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 311, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
  File "/private/tmp/Paranoid.app/Contents/Resources/Paranoid.py", line 4, in <module>
    import cv
  File "cv.pyc", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2.cv
```

There is no such error when I am executing app in project folder. How can I fix this problem?